# Operator overloading = and []

Tags: c++, oop, syntax-error

Right now, I must write

```
st[1];
st = 5;
```

What must I change in my code to be able to do this:

```
st[1] = 5;
```

---

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A
{
public:
  A(){this->z = 0;}
  void operator = (int t)  { this->x[this->z] = t+10; }
  int& operator [] (int t) { this->z=t; return this->x[t]; }
private:
  int x[2];
  int z;
};
void main()
{
  A st;
  st[0]=9;
  cout<<st[0]; 
  system("pause");
}
```

**UPD:** Now I see 9 instead 19.

Comment: Return your int by reference for operator[]

Comment: Return a reference from `operator[]`. Beware that this breaks encapsulation of the value held in members exposed this way completely.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you think `st[1];` does. It surely _doesn't_ select array element 1 for the next independent statement, if that's what you want. `st[1]; st=5;` and `st[1] = 5` are two totally different things.

Comment: I need use class A like an array with size =2. Each element of this array is a sum st[0]=5 <- of this number and some const. (in my example it's equal 10)

Comment: Maybe so, but what I'm saying is that `st[1];` as in your above code snippet simply does nothing (regardless of whether you implement `operator[]` return-by-value or correctly return-by-reference as by Andy Prowl's answer). It's a value (or reference) that is being ignored, much as `(void)0;`. It simply doesn't do anything. You really have to make it _one statement_ with the assignment to achieve what you intend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The built-in operator `=` expects an *lvalue* as its left hand operand. Therefore, in order for this statement to compile:

```
st[1] = 5;
```

You need to change the return type of your `operator []` from `int` to `int&`:

```
    int& operator [] (int t) { return this->x[t]; }
//  ^^^^
```

You could also provide a `const` overload, which will return a reference to `const` if the object on which `operator []` is invoked is `const`:

```
    int const& operator [] (int t) const { return this->x[t]; }
//  ^^^^^^^^^^                     ^^^^^
```

Comment: There's no point in returning a `const&` from the `const` member function, as the `int` is sufficiently small just to copy (although this should be optimised away, inlined and effectively irrelevant).

Comment: @AlexChamberlain: Well, there could be a point. If I have a reference, I could see changes to that value. If I returned a value, that would be impossible. This way, the client chooses. It's all about value semantics vs reference semantics.

Comment: I never thought of keeping the reference around, though that sounds like it could dangle pretty easily.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain: Like all observing pointers/references. It may or may not make sense, depending on the particular design.